# RavenDB : How can I Savechanges only for specific objects

Tags: ravendb

In an MVC application, for a request, I create a document session and retrieve a bunch of objects and process them in memory. During this period if there is an error, I create an Error object and store it in Raven. When I call SaveChanges to store this Error object, the state of all the other objects in memory get saved too. I need to avoid this. How can I fire Savechanges only for the Error object?
We use StructureMap to get the instance of DocumentSession:

```
public RavenDbRegistry(string connectionStringName)
{
    For<IDocumentStore>()
        .Singleton()
        .Use(x =>
        {
            var documentStore = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = connectionStringName };
            documentStore.Initialize();         
            return documentStore;
        }
        )
        .Named("RavenDB Document Store.");
    For<IDocumentSession>()
        .HttpContextScoped()
        .Use(x =>
        {
            var documentStore = x.GetInstance<IDocumentStore>();
            return documentStore.OpenSession();
        })
        .Named("RavenDb Session -> per Http Request.");
}
```

This is how I save the Error Object:

```
private void SaveError(Error error)
{
    documentSession.Store(error);
    documentSession.SaveChanges();
}
```

Couple of variations that I have tried which didn't work as desired:
1. Creating a new DocumentSession just for error logging:

```
private void SaveError(Error error)
{
    var documentStore = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB" };
    documentStore.Initialize();
    using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
    {
        documentSession.Store(error);
        documentSession.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

2. Wrapping within a TransactionScope

```
private void SaveError(Error error)
{
    using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
    {
        documentSession.Store(error);
        documentSession.SaveChanges();
        tx.Complete();
    }
}
```

Currently I am not sure what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

************ *UPDATE* ******************

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the below line before SaveChanges

documentSession.Advanced.Clear();.

So now my SaveError looks like this:

```
private void SaveError(Models.CMSError error)
        {
            documentSession.Advanced.Clear();
            documentSession.Store(error);
            documentSession.SaveChanges();            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new document session - but on the existing document store, not on a new one.

Inject an `IDocumentStore` and call `OpenSession` on that.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I still have to try out your solution. For the time being the change I have mentioned in my post worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the below line before SaveChanges

```
documentSession.Advanced.Clear();.
```

So now my SaveError looks like this:

```
private void SaveError(Models.CMSError error)
        {
            documentSession.Advanced.Clear();
            documentSession.Store(error);
            documentSession.SaveChanges();            
        }
```